# Why does chlorine show a mesomeric effect in haloarenes and an inductive effect in haloalkanes?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, resonance, inductive-effect, halogens

Chlorine shows the +R effect in haloarenes and the -I effect in haloalkanes. Does chlorine do the same for all cyclic compounds or only for aromatic rings? Is this just another experimentally seen fact about chlorine or is there a higher mechanism involved?

Comment: Chlorine is always +R and -I, regardless of the compound.

Comment: In aromatic rings like benzene it shows less pulling of electron towards itself when compared to alkanes why is this so? Sorry if I caused any confusion, it'd be a great help if you could elaborate on your answer!

Comment: Because in the aromatic case it other than pulling the electrons also gets a chance to donate electrons whereas in the aliphatic case it can only pull.

Comment: Quoting myself, "Theoretical reason why ...."

Comment: Why, because it has a lone pair of electrons which are almost in plane with the aromatic system. Chlorine lp can also resonate.

Comment: Oh man ;) I'm the one who added that into the question but sure :P @DhruvDesai

Comment: The thing is to show +R , you need to have something into which the lone pairs can resonate into , maybe you should compare arenes with other conjugated systems

Comment: @Buraian yes all credits go to them to correct my broken chemistry english.

Comment: There is a book named David R Klein's Organic Chemistry, you should check out the conjugated dienes chapter. It starts a bit heavy with MO theory but it is understandable with HS knowledge only. I think that would give you some more insight into how conjugation works.

Comment: So, if I'm not wrong its because of the partial double bond nature of benzene?

Comment: Not just partial, it's in the way that the electrons are pushed that a meaningful delocalization of electrons take place

Comment: Translation: +/- R effect = +/- M effect -> Mesomeric effect, see Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mesomeric_effect